# How do I change the color scheme of tables in PowerPivot Data View?

Tags: database, excel, formatting, powerpivot

The default color scheme for tables in *Data View* in Excel PowerPivot is very bland-- white rows with hard to see gridlines. I noticed that on YouTube videos, however, everyone seems to have colorful tables in PowerPivot Data View. Image 1 shows my *Data View* while Image 2 shows a YouTuber's *Data View*. How can I add color to my *Data View*?

Image 1--My Data View

[image: Image 1--My Data View]

Image 2-- YouTuber's Data View

[image: Image 2-- YouTuber's Data View]

Comment: I found this, but it doesn't seem to work for me. https://www.kasperonbi.com/wow-how-did-you-get-that-fancy-powerpivot-window-color/

Comment: Yep, I found that same link and I tried his solution but I only ended up changing the color scheme of my Excel tables, from which my *Data Model* draws data. However, I was unable to change the look of my *Data View*.